# save pytorch model and load in new file

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I am working on a quantum machine learning program. I've gotten the program to work, but it has to re-train every time I run the program. I'd like to train the model, save it, and then run a separate file using the trained model each time I want to run the program. This would save a lot of time because training takes about 40 mins. Here's what I wrote originally:

```
model_hybrid = train_model(
model_hybrid, criterion, optimizer_hybrid, exp_lr_scheduler, num_epochs=num_epochs)

visualize_model(model_hybrid, num_images=batch_size)
plt.show()
```

This works perfectly.

I then tried to save the `model_hybrid` model to a file so I can open it in a different python session:

```
torch.save(model_hybrid.state_dict(),r'C:\Users\chase\OneDrive\Desktop\_data\machine_learning_files\model_1')
```

When checking the type of this `model_hybrid`, it shows `<class 'torchvision.models.resnet.ResNet'>`

When I try to load the saved file with the following code:

```
model_hybrid=torch.load(r'C:\Users\chase\OneDrive\Desktop\_data\machine_learning_files\model_1')
```

and try to run it by calling `visualize_model()`, it doesn't work. When checking the type of `model_hybrid`, it is `<class 'collections.OrderedDict'>`

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

According to the pytorch documentation (https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html), when you save the state_dict of a model you are saving a Python dictionary.

This code example creates a model, saves it to a file, and loads it again.

```
import torchvision.models as models
import torch

model_one = models.densenet121(pretrained=True)
torch.save(model_one.state_dict(), 'model.pt')
path_loader = torch.load('model.pt')

model_two = models.densenet121(pretrained=True)
model_two.load_state_dict(path_loader)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving state_dict from torch during the training process. For test time or when you want to use the trained model you can use load_state_dict function from torch.

```
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(path))
```